# The best way to avoid PMD.ExcessiveParameterList

Tags: apex, pmd

I'm aware of `@SuppressWarnings('PMD.ExcessiveParameterList')` but from my perspective it isnt a great idea. So i prepared kinda wrapper like this

```
public with sharing class PayloadWrapper {
public String token;
public String subscriberKey;
public String page;
public String pageSize;

public PayloadWrapper(String token, String subscriberKey, Integer page, Integer pageSize) {
    this.token = token;
    this.subscriberKey = subscriberKey;
    this.page = String.valueOf(page);
    this.pageSize = String.valueOf(pageSize);
}
public PayloadWrapper(String token, String subscriberKey) {
    this.token = token;
    this.subscriberKey = subscriberKey;
}}
```

let's say - there is a need to add more extra params to the constructor. I think it's possible to provide the constructor with either Map or Set and use it inside. Could you suggest something else?

Maybe we can consider setters for each property?

Or even provide kinda JSON as a string? (dont think it's agreat idea - so many efforts are expected)

Comment: Builder design pattern might be handy - https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder for those kind of scenarios

Comment: @kurunve sure but it looks like providing kinda setter for each property, isn't it?

Comment: so i belive it's better to try split all the params and create kinda 3 classes instead of providing the whole list to constructor

Comment: Builder pattern is my go-to almost always - self-documenting, extensible. A bit tedious to set up but modern IDEs like IlluminateCloud will do this in one click

Comment: +1 for the builder pattern. Way easier for people reading the code as each parameter has a named setter instead the reader having to compare positions.